# Resistance values for open drain

Tags: open-drain

I am trying to establish SPI connection between C8051F931 and SD card. One of the sample programs I have found contains the following comments.

```
// P0.0 - SPI SCK    (digital output, push-pull)
// P0.1 - SPI MISO   (digital input, open-drain)
// P0.2 - SPI MOSI   (digital output, push-pull)
// P0.3 - SPI NSS    (digital output, push-pull)
```

Do I have to connect some resistance in both the case (push-pull,open-drain) ?  if yes what values?

Answer (score 1):

Push-pull digital outputs require no pull-up or pull-down resistor. They are outputs that produce either a high or a low voltage close to the supply voltages.

Open-drain digital inputs are a little bit of a contradiction unless one presumes it is a digitally configurable input/output where the output is an open-drain and not push-pull configuration. If used as an input I suggest a 10k pull-up resistor. If used as an output 10k may do but so might 1k if the output is expected to switch greater than a few hundred micro-amps.

Answer (score 1):

When an output pin is open drain and the device that its drives expects to be driven by a push-pull output you will have to provide the missing 'pull to high' in some way, a pull-up resistor being the most common way.

The only open drain pin in your list is marked MISO, which means Master In / Slave Out. That means that for your microcontroller this is an *input*, so the output stage of the microcontroller is not used and hence irrelevant.

Note that when the corresponding SD card pin is open drain, you will still need a pull-up resistor.